# Angular - Get Boolean Value from a Observable Service inside the CanActivate

Tags: angular, observable

I'm trying to get the boolean value and return it inside the `CanActivate` in angular.

Here's my sample service:

```
isActiveUser<bool>(){
    return this.http.get<boolean>(apiGetUserStatus);
}
```

Here's my `canActivateMethod`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshow): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean){
    var status = this.myService.isActiveUser().subscribe((active: boolean)=>{
        return active;
    })

    return status;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to console log the `status` it shows the observable stuff, not the actual boolean value. Any help regarding this?

Comment: Because ```subscribe``` returns ```Subscription```, if you want to work with ```active: boolean``` parameter you can assign it to some variable and return this variable

Comment: You are assigning `status` to the subscription, not the result. `active` is the result and it is not returned from the `canActivate` method. It's the return of the subscription. You have some options, like wrapping the subscription in a Promise. Await the Promise to resolve the `active` value and then return the `active` value from `canActivate`.

Answer (score 2):

canActivate can also return an observable. So just change your code this way.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
        const subject = new Subject<boolean>();
        this.myService.isActiveUser().subscribe((result) => {
            subject.next(result);
        });
        return subject;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the need for the `Subject` here? The call could simply be returned. Also the subscription might be left open now since `Subject` is multi-cast.

Comment: This will be used for some checks if result is object instead of boolean value.. Like if (result.isVIsible) { subject.next(false) } likewise

Comment: @DevangPatel: That is better done using operators: `this.myService.isActiveUser().pipe(map(result => { return result.isVisible ? false : true }));`

Answer (score 1):

Try to just return the `isActiveUser()` function.

```js
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshow
): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.myService.isActiveUser();
}
```

#### Update: additional logic from `isActiveUser()`

You could use RxJS operators like `map` or `tap` to either transform the data or perform some-effects from the result of `isActiveUser()`.

```js
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshow
): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.myService.isActiveUser().pipe(
    map((activeUser: boolean) => {
      // do something
      return isUserAdmin();   // <-- eg.: function that returns boolean
    }),
    tap((user: boolean) => {
      // do some side-effects
      // tap doesn't have to return anything
    }),
    switchMap((user: boolean) => {
      // you could also map to another observable using `switchMap`
      return someFunc(); // <-- eg: function returns an `Observable<boolean>`
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Michael, what if I need to do additional logic for the result of the `isActiveUser()`?

Comment: For example,`var result = this.myService.isActiveUser()`? and the `result`, I need to work on some logic before I return the boolean data?

Comment: @JokerBench: `var result = this.myService.isActiveUser()` doesn't provide the boolean, it provides `Observable<boolean>`.

Comment: I just have a question, can we just return directly the boolean inside the `map((activeUser: boolean) => {
      // do something
      return isUserAdmin();   // <-- eg.: function that returns boolean
    }),`?

Comment: @JokerBench: Could you elaborate a little more? We are returning a boolean at the moment from the `map` operator.

Comment: Just confirming, so we can directly return the `activeUser` inside the `map` right?

Comment: @JokerBench: Yes you can. `map((activeUser: boolean) => { // do something; return activeUser; })`